# ¿Como mostrar un GIF en un PictureBox usando hilos en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo dos `Windows Form`, el principal tiene en el medio de la pantalla un `PictureBox` que a su vez este contiene un `GIF` de una animación "cargando". La idea es que cuando el segundo `Form` se le active el evento `load` se cargue primero el método donde tengo el hilo, posteriormente se ejecute todo el código restante (métodos,etc) y al final se ejecute otro método que cambiara la propiedad `visible`  a `false`.
Me explico con el código:

```
    private void FrmHijo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
       FrmPrincipal.Instancia.mCarga();
       /*---------------------Codigo-----------------------------*/
       FrmPrincipal.Instancia.mDefault();    
     }
```

Este es el método `mCarga()`:

```
public void mCarga()
  {
      ThreadStart delegado = new ThreadStart(mostrasPTBX);
      Thread hilo = new Thread(delegado);
      hilo.Start();
      Cursor.Hide();
  }
```

Este es el método al que apunta el delegado:

```
public void mostrasPTBX()
  {
      FrmPrincipal.Instancia.ptbImagenCarga.Visible = true;
      FrmPrincipal.Instancia.ptbImagenCarga.BringToFront();
  }
```

Y este es el método `mDefault` que solo oculta el `PictureBox`:

```
public void mDefault()
   {
      FrmPrincipal.Instancia.ptbImagenCarga.Visible = false;
      FrmPrincipal.Instancia.ptbImagenCarga.BringToFront();
      Cursor.Show();
   }
```

El problema esta en que al momento de abrir el `FormHijo` y se activa el evento `Load` no pone visible el `PictureBox` simplemente me oculta el `Cursor` como lo indique en el mismo método, ya intente poniendo un `MessageBox` en el método `mostrasPTBX()` y si me los mostro al carga el `FormHijo`. Otra cosa, intente hacerlo sin hilos solo llame el metodo `mostrasPTBX()` dentro del método  `mCarga()` pero igual tuve el mismo problema. Probablemente el problema sea ajeno a los hilos ademas que soy relativamente nuevo programando. Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: Si eres nuevo programando, la idea de usar hilos me parece un poco avanzada. Mas alla de eso, probaste de hacer un refresh del form? parece que nadie esta disparando eso, y con todo lo que estas haciendo puede que no tenga tiempo de hacerlo.

Comment: bueno soy relativamente nuevo, si ya lo intente tampoco me funciono

Comment: Lo que veo con el hilo, es que tu codigo pierde ese hilo. Fijate que haces el start. nadie hace el stop de ese hilo. Es mas, perdes la referencia al mismo. Deberias primero lograr que funcione sin hilos, porque ademas, cuando disparas un hilo no puedes modificar cosas de otro hilo directamente.

Comment: Parece que estás intentando hacer una pantalla de carga. Una firma facil, si quieres usar hilos, es cargar el form que hace el trabajo, hacer el trabajo en un hilo, y llamar la pantalla de carga desde este, y cuando acabe el trabajo cerrarlo.